# Limit Foreign Key Options in Django Select

Tags: python, django

I have a model for Supplier and another model for Product.  Each Product must have a Supplier instance associated to it.  Later on, in a separate model form for the Proforma model, the user has to select a Supplier and then a Product.  What I'd like to see happen is the Product select options filter down to Products where the Supplier = the Supplier the user has selected. I am not finding much on how to handle this use case...could anyone point me in the right direction?  Will this require the use of JS or can I do something to set this in the form directly? Or maybe pass a queryset from the view to this field? Anything even some resource on this would be helpful.

models.py

```
class Supplier(models.Model):
    supplierName = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Product(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(Supplier, null=False, blank=False)

class Proforma(models.Model): 
    ...
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(Supplier, null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    code = models.ForeignKey(Product, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a separate URL that will return product based on the supplier.
Make an ajax call after selecting supplier, load the response in product select options.